# How are percentiles used for value clipping in the quantisation of neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

According to [Quantization for Neural Networks](https://leimao.github.io/article/Neural-Networks-Quantization/) webpage,

> Quantization maps a floating point value $x \in [\alpha, \beta]$ to a *b*-bit integer $x_q \in [\alpha_q, \beta_q]$.
> In practice, the quantization process will have chance to have $x$
> that is outside the range of $[\alpha, \beta]$, thus the quantized value $x_q$ will also be outside the range of $[\alpha_q, \beta_q]$. If the integer type is signed *INTb* and $[\alpha_q, \beta_q] = (-2^{b-1}, 2^{b-1}-1)$, or unsigned *UINTb* and $[\alpha_q, \beta_q] = (0, 2^b-1)$, programming languages that have fixed type-precisions will clip the values that are outside the range.

There is an approach of value clipping that works based on the percentiles. It is mentioned in [Trained quantization thresholds for accurate and efficient fixed-point inference of deep neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.08066.pdf) paper by Jain, Gural, Wu and Dick:

> IBM's FAQ uses percentile initialization to determine clipping thresholds

My question is what is the process of useing percentiles for value clipping?
I appreciate the detailed explanation (preferably with an example).